# calling ApplicationView::GetForCurrentView() returns error in uwp app

Tags: c++, windows, uwp

This is how I call this. to resize window of the app

```
auto view = ApplicationView::GetForCurrentView();
view.SetPreferredMinSize({ 300, 200 });
Window::Current().Activate();
```

and the error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "public: static struct
> winrt::Windows::UI::ViewManagement::ApplicationView __cdecl
> winrt::Windows::UI::ViewManagement::ApplicationView::GetForCurrentView(void)"
> (?GetForCurrentView@ApplicationView@ViewManagement@UI@Windows@winrt@@SA?AU12345@XZ)   BluetoothLE C:\Users\berkin1\Desktop\BluetoothLE\cppwinrt\App.obj   1

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "public: bool __cdecl winrt::impl::consume_Windows_UI_ViewManagement_IApplicationView3<struct winrt::Windows::UI::ViewManagement::ApplicationView>::TryResizeView(struct winrt::Windows::Foundation::Size const &)const " (?TryResizeView@?$consume_Windows_UI_ViewManagement_IApplicationView3@UApplicationView@ViewManagement@UI@Windows@winrt@@@impl@winrt@@QEBA_NAEBUSize@Foundation@Windows@3@@Z) BluetoothLE D:\BluetoothLE\cppwinrt\BlankPage.obj 1

Comment: Sounds like you're using an ancient version of C++/WinRT and forgot to include the correct header file. Which version of C++/WinRT are you using and which headers are you including?

Comment: vs2019 latest sdk

Comment: You forgot to include winrt/Windows.UI.ViewManagement.h

Comment: The latest SDK ships some v1 release of C++/WinRT. That's ancient. Use the NuGet package instead (v2 currently). It'll [fail with a compiler error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57450168/1889329) instead, that's easier to parse and respond to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This is how I call this. to resize window of the app

If you want to resize your app, please call [`TryResizeView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.viewmanagement.applicationview.tryresizeview?view=winrt-19041#Windows_UI_ViewManagement_ApplicationView_TryResizeView_Windows_Foundation_Size_) method after setting preferred min Size.

```
auto view = ApplicationView::GetForCurrentView();
view->SetPreferredMinSize({ 300,200 });
view->TryResizeView({ 300,200 });
```

And please make sure above code run in the ui thread.

Comment: should i include smth in the header for this? i mirrored same still same error https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/ResizeAppView/cppwinrt/Scenario1_Basic.cpp

Comment: Please check your pch content if has include include  [`winrt/Windows.UI.ViewManagement.h`](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/ResizeAppView/cppwinrt/pch.h#L9) header as   Raymond Chen  said.