# Built in Boolean to Visibility converter wont compile

Tags: visual-c++, c++-winrt

I'm trying to bind Visibility to `ToggleButton::IsChecked` using automatic IReference to Visibility conversion

```xml
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <CheckBox x:Name="myButton" Content="Click Me" />
    <TextBlock Text="Hello" Visibility="{x:Bind myButton.IsChecked, Mode=OneWay}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

In a blank project this works. In my existing project it will work if I provide my own converter, but if I try to use auto conversion, I get:

```
error C3779: 'winrt::impl::consume_Windows_Foundation_IReference<
winrt::Windows::Foundation::IReference<bool>,T>::Value':
a function that returns 'auto' cannot be used before it is defined
with [ T=bool ] (compiling source file Generated Files\XamlTypeInfo.g.cpp)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting "a function that returns 'auto' cannot be used before it is defined" while using CoreDispatcher::RunAsync in C++/WinRT project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57450168/getting-a-function-that-returns-auto-cannot-be-used-before-it-is-defined-whi)

Comment: Note that you're getting the error while *"compiling source file Generated Files\XamlTypeInfo.g.cpp"*.

Comment: @IInspectable I understand the error, but `MyControl.xaml.g.hpp includes pch.h which includes Windows.Foundation.h which has the definition of Value`.  I don't understand why only `Windows.Foundation.0.h` is being found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you compile for c++17 the error goes away. I was compiling for c++20

https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/9214